# how to get values of checked rows in kendo ui grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to get the rows value of selected rows in a kendo grid. Please see the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/D6GWf/1/). For example, on a button click, i like to get all the names or ids of selected rows as an array or comma separated string. how can i do that? thanks.

Kendo grid

```
      $('#getNames').click(function(){

//how to get all the names of selected rows?
alert('you have selected these people:')

    });

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "odata",
                        transport: {
                            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                        },
                        pageSize: 10
                    },
                    groupable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                        pageSizes: true,
                        buttonCount: 5
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            field: "", title: "", template: "<input type='checkbox' name='selectcandidate' />"
                        },
                        {
                        field: "ContactName",
                        title: "Contact Name",
                        width: 200
                    }, {
                        field: "ContactTitle",
                        title: "Contact Title",
                        width: 250
                    }, {
                        field: "CompanyName",
                        title: "Company Name"
                    }, {
                        field: "Country",
                        width: 150
                    }]
                });
```

Answer (score 10):

You should do:

```
// Get reference to Grid object
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
// Get selected rows
var sel = grid.select();
// Get data item for each
var items = [];
$.each (sel, function(idx, row) {
    var item = grid.dataItem(row);
    items.push(item);
});
// Show results
console.log("items", items);
```

The only question is that you need to retrieve the data item one at a time and then build an array with all of them if that's what you need.

Check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XNcmt/71/

**EDIT** If you want to get those rows that have the checkbox clicked, then you should do:

```
// Get reference to Grid object
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
// Get selected rows
var sel = $("input:checked", grid.tbody).closest("tr");
// Get data item for each
var items = []; 
$.each (sel, function(idx, row) {
    var item = grid.dataItem(row);
    items.push(item);
});
alert ("selected: " + JSON.stringify(items));
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XNcmt/72/